# Whats the difference between a sekonic light meter CINE version vs non-cine version

Tags: lighting

I'm looking into getting a used Sekonic light meter, my question is what are the advantages of getting 'CINE' version light meters Sekonic makes versus the regular versions. I'm going to be primarily working with video, but some still work to, and a lot of just testing to understand light.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're working with video, the cine model is the one you want. It lets you meter for motion, not just ISO, f stops, and shutter speeds. I've had the 758 for years... great meter.

Answer (score 0):

Functionally, they're the same, but the Cine version allows you to select shutter speeds associated with motion picture frame rates - 24fps= 1/48th of a second, etc. I have the 708; I'm not sure if later models included provisions to adjust for various shutter angles...but the 708 does not. Or at least I've not found the feature.